# Unable to access controller scope from the view

Tags: angularjs

I need to access the following scope in my directive's controller: "$scope.historySelectionFieldValues".  I am not getting anything populated.  Here is my view.

**View**

```
<ji-select-box ng-repeat="{{historySelectionFieldValues}}"></ji-select-box>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('FormBuilder') 
        .directive('jiSelectBox', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                scope: {},
                controller: function($scope){
                    $scope.historySelectionFieldValues = [
                        "Item1", //THIS IS MY ARRAY THAT I AM STUCK DISPLAYING
                        "Item2"
                    ];
                },                    
                template: function (element, attrs) {                   
                    var dxAttributes = "";
                    return '</div>' +
                        '<div class="dx-field-value" dx-select-box="{ ' + dxAttributes + ' }"></div>' +
                        '</div>'
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that

1. You could pass that variable to the directive as an argument where you are calling the directive.

   ```
   <jiSelectBox historySelectionFieldValues="historySelectionFieldValues">
   ```

   ....
2. You could use root scope. For this you need to have root scope accessible in the directive like below

angular.module('FormBuilder') 
                 .directive('jiSelectBox', function (**$rootScope**) {
        ....
         });

Then you can use it in your directive template like below :

```
$root.historySelectionFieldValues
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Your first option is exactly what I am trying to do.  I want an attribute that I can reference in the scope of the directive and it will pick it up.  I want the attrs value "historySelectionFieldValues" to come from the controller array.  I have put together a JSFiddle can you see what I'm missing based on your first suggestion? http://jsfiddle.net/Laf4d5e2/21/

Comment: Where are you trying to access this variable ? I dont see it being used anywhere. Is there a reason why you are building your template dynamically ?

Comment: The "param" variable?  Is that what you are referring to?  If so, I was thinking I could add it as a scope attribute that way it could be picked up. And yes, I have to build the form templates dynamically this way and with DevExpress. I am almost completed.  The select box is actually the last piece I have to get working. I don't really care how I access the array in the controller, I just have to figure out some way that works.

Comment: Do you have any additional thoughts to this issue?

Comment: You are including controller within the scope of directive. That controller is not directive's parent controller. I have changed the plunker a bit to have a variable in parent controller, I am passing it then to directive. http://jsfiddle.net/greengrassbluesky/fgf0qbx6/1/ I am still not clear though how and where you want to use this array. but i have created a linker function that you can call, it will then print the value in console.